# How to make windows service start automatically

Tags: .net, windows-services, startup

I am trying to make a windows service to start automatically before you are in a session.
I have tried using `TopShelf` and adding the `Start Automatically` method, but the service does not get started when i start the computer.I still have to start it manually.
Is there anything i am missing ?

**Service Start**

```
public static void RunService() {
            var exitCode = HostFactory.Run(x => {
                x.Service<SomeService>(s => {
                    s.ConstructUsing((h) => new SomeService());
                    s.WhenStarted(t => t.Start());
                    s.WhenStopped(t => t.Stop());
                    s.WhenSessionChanged((daemon, host, args) => daemon.SessionChanged(args.SessionId));
                });
                x.EnableSessionChanged();
                x.EnableShutdown();

                x.StartAutomatically();
                x.RunAsLocalSystem();

            });
            int exitCodeValue = (int)Convert.ChangeType(exitCode, exitCode.GetTypeCode());
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check the Services Control Panel application ("services.msc") and
   confirm that your service's startup type is "Automatic".
2. Using the Event Viewer, check the **Windows Logs > Application** area for
   messages from your service. Perhaps it is starting at boot but
   crashing or stopping quickly.
3. Using the Event Viewer, check the **Windows Logs > System** area of the event logs for errors starting your service. Review records where the source is "Service Control Manager".

See "[Why doesn’t my Windows Service Start at Boot?](https://www.coretechnologies.com/blog/windows-services/windows-service-start-at-boot/)" for additional advice.